# Pointers to char

Tags: c++

```
char* pStr = new String("Hello");
char* s = "Hello";
```

Is the first one correct? Are there any difference between these two? My guess is that the first one is allocated on the heap,and the other one an the stack.Am i correct or are there any other differences?

Comment: The `C` tag should be removed if you are using concepts like `new`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one is just incorrect and won't compile because there is no such thing as `String` in either C or C++. The second one will compile, and is fine in C(afaik). In C++, however, the conversion from a string literal to `char*` is deprecated. You can unintentionally write later `s[0] = 'X';` which is undefined behavior.

The correct way of doing it is using const (in C++)

```
const char * s = "Hello";
```

or, better, use string

```
std::string s("Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

pStr and s are pointers, so it is important to distinguish between the pointers themselves and the data that they point to.

On the first line, pStr is a pointer to an instance of the String class allocated on the heap. The string data inside this instance is a copy of a literal string "Hello" that is stored in the program's [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). The copying is done by the String constructor. (You've referred to a String class, but I assume you mean std::string).

On the second line, s is a pointer to data stored in the program's data segment. Data in the data segment is immutable, so s should really be const char *.

There isn't enough information in your example to tell whether pStr and s are stored on the heap or the stack. If they are variables inside a function then they are on the stack. If there are members of a class then they are on the heap if the class was instantiated on the help (using new) or on the stack if it is instantiated as a value.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
char* pStr = new std::string("Hello");
```

will cause a compiler semantic error, because the LHS has a type of `char*` and the RHS has a type of `std::string`.

The line

```
char* s = "Hello"
```

will compile, but may give a warning, because the LHS has a type of `char*` and the RHS has a type of `const char*`.